# How are self referencing formula fields handled using Replication API?

Tags: api, formula, replication

My understanding is that formula fields or rollups are not calculated in the object that is being queried using the Replication API. Is this also the case if the formula field value is calculated from data within the record itself? i.e. time dependant formula value?